# How to format negative decimal numbers in xslt?

Tags: xslt, format, decimal, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

problem is with specified input, I have an input in  which is something like this, -0.982983928391353
and i want to format that to -0.98298 ( upto 5 decimal points) this is the sample input xml below.

```
    <rs>
      <R>
      <C0>vo</C0>
      <C1>f_item</C1>
      <C2>1</C2>
      <C3>4</C3>
      <C4>Stores</C4>
      <C5>2011-10-13T00:00:00</C5>
      <C6>Active</C6>
      <C7>Supplier</C7>
      </R>
      <R>
      <C0>SManufacturing</C0>
      <C1>KB18759</C1>
      <C2>-0.1002345678907564</C2>
      <C3>2</C3>
      <C4>Stores</C4>
      <C5>1999-02-03T00:00:00</C5>
      <C6>Active</C6>
      <C7>Supplier</C7>
      </R>
      </rs>
```

the required output is

```
      <rs>
      <R>
      <C0>vo</C0>
      <C1>f_item</C1>
      <C2>1.00000</C2>
      <C3>4.00000</C3>
      <C4>Stores</C4>
      <C5>2011-10-13T00:00:00</C5>
      <C6>Active</C6>
      <C7>Supplier</C7>
      </R>
      <R>
      <C0>SManufacturing</C0>
      <C1>KB18759</C1>
      <C2>-0.10023</C2>
      <C3>2.00000</C3>
      <C4>Stores</C4>
      <C5>1999-02-03T00:00:00</C5>
      <C6>Active</C6>
      <C7>Supplier</C7>
      </R>
      </rs>
```

I tried with this, but this works for positive integers only. It doesn format -0.1002345678907564..

```
<xsl:template match="node()"> 
    <xsl:copy>          
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*| node()"/>

    </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match = "*[not(*)][translate(.,'0123456789.*****', '') = '']">

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(.), '0.00000')"/>

    </xsl:copy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't understand the use of `translate()`.  The second argument is a key string of individual characters, duplicating the `*` is irrelevant.  The third argument is a string of corresponding translation characters, of which you have none, so it is simply removing the characters from the input.  Your test, even with the addition of `-`, would accept the string "123-45.678.9" as a number.

It is not a pattern matcher, which is implied by your post.

If you want to check in XSLT 1.0 that an element has no child elements and is numeric, this should work:

```
match="*[not(*)][number(.)=number(.)]"
```

... which works on the principle that NaN is not equal to NaN.

Answer (score 1):

`'0123456789.*****'` is missing `-`.